# CSS selector not working with children

Tags: html, css, parent-child, media

I want to add some css rules to .container.picture but only in .medium-width.
HTML is:

```
<div class="block medium-width">
  <div class="container picture">
    <img src="img/car4.png" title="Car">
  </div>
  <div class="container text">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS is:

```
.medium-width > .container.picture
    {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
```

Is something wrong in this selector?

Comment: And what doesn't work? This selector is valid.

Comment: Looks like it should work perfectly - you can verify it by adding something like `border: 1px solid red` and see if it applies.

Comment: It would be much easier to see your problem and help you if we had some context. Could you perhaps make jsfiddle if you still cant get it to work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/kdrcabd4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
You may have other rules applied, or a context that prevent this selector from working.
But here, selector's right